# Systemd status sees slice but disable does not

Tags: systemd

I'm trying to disable the following slice. Status shows that it's active, but when I go to disable it, it doesn't exist. I read somewhere that this could possibly be an SELinux issue. We do have SELinux enabled, but I don't know much about it.

```
sudo systemctl disable 'system-dbus\\x2d:1.8\\x2dorg.kde.powerdevil.backlighthelper.slice'
```

> ```
> Failed to disable unit: Unit file system-dbus\x2d:1.8\x2dorg.kde.powerdevil.backlighthelper.slice does not exist.
> ```

```
sudo systemctl status 'system-dbus\\x2d:1.8\\x2dorg.kde.powerdevil.backlighthelper.slice'
```

> ```
> ● system-dbus\x2d:1.8\x2dorg.kde.powerdevil.backlighthelper.slice - Slice /system/dbus-:1.8-org.kde.powerdevil.backlighthelper
>      Loaded: loaded
>      Active: active since Tue 2023-02-14 10:28:27 EST; 18min ago
>       Until: Tue 2023-02-14 10:28:27 EST; 18min ago
>       Tasks: 0
>      Memory: 48.0K
>         CPU: 28ms
>      CGroup: /system.slice/system-dbus\x2d:1.8\x2dorg.kde.powerdevil.backlighthelper.slice
>
>  Feb 14 10:28:27 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Created slice Slice /system/dbus-:1.8-org.kde.powerdevil.backlighthelper.
>  Feb 14 10:28:27 localhost.localdomain backlighthelper[2715]: org.kde.powerdevil: no kernel backlight interface found
> ```

Comment: It's possible it is active (started) but not enabled.  Can you `systemctl cat ...` it to see the unit file?  I suspect you just need to `systemctl stop` instead of `systemctl disable`

Comment: OK, that's helpful. I didn't know about cat and had been looking for the relevant file. I will try tomorrow when I'm in the office.

Comment: `enable`/`disable` only act on the `[Install]` section of a unit, creating/deleting links as appropriate.  If there's no `[Install]` section, or the unit isn't enabled, then there's nothing to delete on `disable`.  `start`/`stop` actually start/stop that unit.  It's possible that your unit is triggered by another unit and so you'd need to look at what creates it.  Often there is a `TriggeredBy:` sentence in `systemctl status` when that happens.  (At least there is for services which are triggered by sockets, timers, or paths)

Comment: I couldn't see anything with cat, but you are right. Stop/mask work just fine. Perhaps a more appropriate error message would be "Section in unit file ... does not exist".